# Was bedeutet "Smeck" in einem Gedicht von Till Lindemann?

Tags: vocabulary

Das Gedicht *Bleib* von Till Lindemann lautet:

> Still liegt in meinem Arm
>   was ich nicht lassen kann
>   ein Hort für **Smeck** und Nissen
>   mein gutes altes Kissen

Weiß jemand was *Smeck* ist? Ist das eine Abkürzung von etwas? Ich kann es nicht im Wörterbuch finden.

Comment: Could be "Schmeckt", or from Russian "смех" (laughter).

Comment: Da im Zusammenhang mit Nissen (Läuseeiern) genannt, könnte es sich ebenfalls um eine Form von Dreck handeln, etwa Fett von Haut und Haaren, das sich bei langem Gebrauch ohne Waschen ins Kissen überträgt. (Hört sich  auch wie Schmalz + Dreck an)

Comment: Die Schreibung *sm-* deutet an, daß es sich nicht um ein Wort des Standarddeutschen handelt. Dort gibt es nur *schm-*.

Comment: @philshem "смех" is pronounced "smjech".

Answer (score 4):

Möglicherweise handelt es sich um eine künstlerisch verknappte Version von [Smegma](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smegma) (NSFW).

Mich wundert übrigens, dass der Text nur auf wenigen russischsprachigen Webseiten zu finden ist. Ist dort die Schreibung richtig?

Comment: Hier ein [Google-Books-Link](https://books.google.de/books?id=eFFmAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q=Bleib&f=false).

Answer (score 3):

Smeck ist ein Slangwort für Heroin o.Ä.

Comment: Soweit ich weiß lautet der Slangausdruck [Smack](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=smack)

Comment: @mtwde Haben die Slangwörter so strikte Rechtsschreibung?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Naja, kann man drüber streiten ^^, aber warum soll Lindemann nicht a) den englischen Hauptbegriff nehmen (smeck ist eher eine Variante) bzw. b) nicht den deutschen Ausdruck [Schmack/Schmeck](https://gizbonn.de/giftzentrale-bonn/drogen/slanglexikon/slanglexikon-s). Daher halte ich es für unwahrscheinlicher, dass hier tatsächlich Smeck für Heroin/Narkotika steht. Von meiner Interpretation des Gedichts ganz abgesehen, die diese Bedeutung darin so nicht sieht ^^.

Answer (score -1):

Ich vermute, dass das Wort englischen Ursprungs ist. Im [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Smeck) findet man

> smecks
>
> An increasingly common word denoting any kind of sexual act. Presumably born from a rather lazy attempt to constitute a somewhat censored version of the regular s-word. Similar to the background of words such as jeebus or fawk.

**Update:**

mtwde weist in seinem Kommentar darauf hin, dass die Top-Definition im Urban Dictionary folgende ist:

> Not a full-blown smooch but a little more than a peck.

Ich schließe mich mtwdes Meinung an, dass "Kuss" im Kontext des Gedichts die bessere Interpretation von "Smeck" ist. In der Tat, "kiss" passt zum Kissen ;-)

Der Vollständigkeit halber hier noch die anderen Definitionen aus dem Urban Dictionary:

1. to laugh, like an idiot... from the russian smekh (смех).
2. To talk care free like an idiot. "Hows the weather?"
   An example can be sited from the film "a clockwork orange" "The Devotchka was smecking away, and not caring about the wicked world one bit." - found when they were in the milk bar for the second time.
3. the unwanted touching of someone else's genitalia to yours; somewhat like frot, but less consensual; frot-rape

**2. Update:**

Ich habe festgestellt, dass es eine [Clockwork-Orange-Revue](https://www.nmz.de/online/geile-gewaltverfuehrung-am-dnt-weimar-knallt-es-in-a-clockwork-orange-mit-rammstein-songs) mit Songs von Rammstein gibt. Das passt zu Definition 2. - dürfte aber Zufall sein.

Comment: Es würde mich schon interessieren, was zum Downvote geführt hat. Vielleicht habe ich zu sehr spekuliert?  Mir ist klar, dass ich hier keine Rückmeldung erwarten kann. Aber mich irritiert vor allem, dass die anderen Antworten mehrere Upvotes bekommen haben, obwohl sie genauso spekulativ sind.

Comment: Sich über Downvotes zu wundern bringt nix. Kann den auch nicht so nachvollziehen. Das Urban Dictionary gibt als Top-Definition allerdings "Not a full-blown smooch but a little more than a peck" an. Passt das nicht besser?

Comment: @mtwde Passt wirklich besser, ich war möglicherweise aufgrund von lejonets "Smegma" auf die andere Definition fixiert ;-)